# Scraping all links within a <div> tag in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm a newbie to web scraping and need help. I'm trying to scrape data from a property site which has got ~20 pages and within each page there are ~18 links to different properties. My end goal is to scrape all the data from each property link. For doing that I'm thinking of running a loop for 20 pages by incrementing page parameter by 1.

But before doing that I need to scrape the data from each property on a single page for which I need links to all the properties on a single page, so need to scrape all links (to properties) from a page. I tried to achieve this using **html_nodes("a")** but in vain.

Here is the page and site I'm trying to scrape.

https://property.jll.co.in/search?city=Hyderabad&mode=list-view&page=0

Here is the piece of code am using to fetch all the links on a single page but not getting desired output. I have also tried with different class and CSS selectors.

```
url <- 'https://property.jll.co.in/search?city=Hyderabad&mode=list-view&page=0'
download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
content <- read_html("scrapedpage.html")

content %>%
html_nodes("a") %>%
head()
```

I would appreciate if someone can help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The site clearly has a ban against scraping that path (and many others) in the [`robots.txt`](https://property.jll.co.in/robots.txt) which means you're violating the terms of service & deliberately bypassing a technical control, both of which can cause/have caused legal issues and potential IP banning. Anyone who helps you may also suffer these penalties and is also treading pretty sketch ethical waters. Just because you _can_ do something does not mean you _should_ or said _thing_ is legal.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks for letting me know..as I said at the start of my post, am a newbie hence didn't know if we could check whether a site allows scraping or not..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That web page builds its structure in your web browser from data in a `<script>` tag. When you download it the JavaScript doesn't run.

```
data = html_text(html_nodes(content,"script")[10])

substr(data,1,100)
### [1] "window.store = {\"properties\":[{\"PropertyId\":\"109667\",\"PropertyName\":\"White House - Block A\",\"Address"
```

You can probably parse that data using a JSON parser in R, if you chop the assignment bit off the start with `substr`:

```
> d = rjson::fromJSON(substr(data,16,nchar(data)))
> names(d)
[1] "properties"            "units_count"           "units_count_text"     
[4] "properties_count_text" "map_data"              "pagination"           
[7] "view_mode"             "query_string"
```

Then you can drill down, for example:

```
> d$map_data[[1]]
$PropertyName
[1] "White House - Block A"

$TransactionType
[1] "For Lease"

$Address
[1] "Kundanbagh Colony"

$ListingTypeDescription
[1] "Lease"
```